# Need to export SQL for creating table(s) from Enterprise Architect

Tags: sql, enterprise-architect

I need to create SQL statements from Enterprise architect v.9 table description, since I need "CREATE TABLE" to be placed in a text file.

Please advice me where to look in EA interface!

Comment: Open the help file and read the chapter called "Database Engineering".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the diagram where your tables are designed, select all of them and right click in one of the tables. Look for *SQL Code Generation* and choose one of the options: single DDL script or not.

The difference is that in the single script all create table statements will be generated in only one file (which is usually better!)

Answer (score 3):

After open your database diagram,

1. Look at **Tools** tab and expand **Database Engineering** menu,
2. Select **Generate Package DLL**,
3. Enter output file name and generate it.

Comment: Now it was moved to Package tab

Answer (score 1):

Select all tables from your diagram and press **F11**.